# Running C program On ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu-11.04

I am new to Ubuntu. I want to run c program on Ubuntu.
I have installed build-essential.
Now I tried following commands to run the program..

```
sudo gedit first.c
```

then typed the basic hello world program. then...

```
cc -c first.c -o first.c
```

But on this command it is showing error as

> No input files.

and also tell me how to run this program.

Comment: You'd be upset if the compiler overwrote your source with the object code as you requested it to do.  Change the final `.c` to `.o`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct usage is:

```
cc -o outputfile myFile.c
```

Then you can run the executable:

```
./outputfile
```

Answer (score 3):

At first you do not have to edit a file as root. That's a bad idea.

The line `cc -c first.c -o first.c` overwrites your C-File you do not want that you want

```
cc first.c -o first
```

and then you want to runs the program
you can to that with

```
./first
```

Comment: but worked fine for compilation but for running it is showing error as 
>Permission Denied

Comment: Then fix the permissions, but don't program as `root` unless you don't mind losing your machine because you make a silly mistake.  It ain't worth it.  Do as little as possible as root.

Answer (score 1):

That compilation command line should have worked. *However* it will **overwrite** your source file.

The `-o` options tells the compiler what to name the output file, and if you name it the same as the source file it will be overwritten.

The first flags you pass to the compiler, `-c`, tells the compiler to generate an *object file*. These object files can later be used by the linker to link with other object files to create the final executable program. It does not, however, create a program you can run.

For creating an executable program from a single source file, do something like:

```
$ cc first.c -o first
```

This will create an executable program (if there are no errors of course) named `first`.

Then to run this program:

```
$ ./first
```

This last command tells the shell to look for `first` in the current directory (which is named `.`), and execute it.

Comment: also works this way $ gcc first.c -o first press enter, then run the executable program as $ ./first ,again press enter

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `.c` on the output file. i.e.

```
cc -c first.c -o first
```

Edit: Oops. You also don't want the `-c`

```
cc -o first first.c
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `-c` and try:

```
cc first.c -o first
   ^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^
    input   output
```

To run:

```
./first
```

Answer (score 0):

Make is configured to recognize certain file extensions by default, so you can simply do:

```
make first
```

Make will then find `first.c` and produce `first` binary executable, and show you what compile command it used. Note that for this to work in a sensible manner, you should have just one first.XXX source file. Also, once you have more than one source file, you need to write a `Makefile`, but with just one source defaults are enough.

To run the produced executable, do

```
./first
```

`./` is needed, because normally working directory is not (and should not be) in PATH in unix environment.

---

Oh yeah, and as mentioned by others: do not use `sudo` for stuff like this. And if you already did that, you can't modify/delete these files as normal user, because they're owned by root. Do `ls -l`, it will show you owners of files. Then you can do `sudo chown yourusername.yoursername file` to change owner of `file` to be owned by `yourusername` (both user and group of file).